# how to check if "chrome" webdriver in vba(Excel) selenium is still active

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, webdriver, instance

I have multiple subs that can use the same webdriver instance, opening and closing the instance is 'time consuming' which is the priority.

this is the summary of my module:

```
Option Explicit
Public testing_webdriver As WebDriver

Sub BrowUp()
    Set testing_webdriver = New WebDriver
    testing_webdriver.Start "chrome"
    testing_webdriver.Window.Maximize
End Sub

Sub BrowDown()
    testing_webdriver.Quit
End Sub


Function myfunct(da_row As Integer)
    
    Dim entityAdress As String
    If Range("F" & da_row).Value = "abrv1" Then
        entityAdress = "site1.com"
    ElseIf Range("F" & da_row).Value = "abrv2" Then
        entityAdress = "site2.com"
    ElseIf Range("F" & da_row).Value = "abrv3" Then
        entityAdress = "site3.com"
    ElseIf Range("F" & da_row).Value = "abrv4" Then
        entityAdress = "site4.com"
    Else
        MsgBox ("cell not in work range")
    End If
    
    testing_webdriver.Get entityAdress 
    testing_webdriver.Wait 1000
    testing_webdriver.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 1000
    testing_webdriver.FindElementByName("login_id").SendKeys "mylogin"
    testing_webdriver.FindElementByName("pass_id").SendKeys "mypass"
    testing_webdriver.FindElementByName("connexion").Click
    testing_webdriver.Timeouts.ImplicitWait = 6000
    testing_webdriver.Wait 1000
    Dim conexStat As String, 
    Range("I" & da_row).Value = testing_webdriver.FindElementById("status").Text
End Function

Sub testconxstat()
    if "testing_webdriver not exist" then
        call BrowUp
    else if
        pass
    end if
    Call myfunct(ActiveCell.Row)
End Sub
```

Is there a way to automatically detect if the webdriver instance is still active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
If Not testing_webdriver Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Webdriver Exists", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "Webdriver Doesn't Exist", vbCritical
End If
```